# Google analytics rendering with filter

Tags: cakephp, google-analytics

hi this is the first time i am working with google analytics and php.

i am trying to get the hits of an url from each browser such as safari, mozilla etc.
in the google data export i am giving my url in the `filters` column for example

```
ga:pagePath==/example/test.php
```

i need the hits of all the browsers, as i am filtering i am getting only the hits of safari that too the last hit.

i want the hits for all browsers and right from the beginning, how to get it......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the google analytics api documentation found here:
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDataFeed.html

in your case i would use the following:

dimension=ga:browser
metric=ga:uniquePageviews